# How do you select all columns, plus the result of a CASE statement in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I want to select *, and not have to type out all individual columns, but I also want to include a custom column with a case statement.  I tried the following:

```
select *, (case when PRI_VAL = 1 then 'High'
                when PRI_VAL = 2 then 'Med'
                when PRI_VAL = 3 then 'Low'
          end) as PRIORITY
from MYTABLE;
```

But it is complaining that

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add an alias for mytable like this:

```
select t.*, (case when PRI_VAL = 1 then 'High'
                when PRI_VAL = 2 then 'Med'
                when PRI_VAL = 3 then 'Low'
          end) as PRIORITY
from MYTABLE t;
```

This is not dependent on any specific Oracle version, not sure about other databases.

Comment: Thanks!  Okay I guess I oversimplified my problem.  What if the columns are the result of a join, i.e. SELECT ... FROM MYTABLE M JOIN ANOTHER A ON M.ID = A.ID?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the answer to this join question.  It's select M.*, A.*, (case ...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

As IronGoofy says, add the table alias.

On a different note be aware that there is a handy searched case syntax that would be suitable for your situation:

```
select t.*,
       case PRI_VAL
         when 1 then 'High' 
         when 2 then 'Med' 
         when 3 then 'Low' 
       end as PRIORITY 
from MYTABLE t;
```

Answer (score -3):

Do it like this:

```
select e.*,
case deptno
when 30 then 'High'
when 20 then 'Medi'
when 10 then 'Low'
else 'Very Low'
end case
from emp e order by deptno desc;
```